# C++ why would my code cut off beginning character of each new output line to command prompt in windows

Tags: c++

I am trying to finalize my tool and I have ran into something that I can't seem to nail down. When I am ending my code using the following:

```
// Create a data stream to capture the server's response
    std::stringstream response_stream;
    char buffer[1024];
    int received_bytes;
    while ((received_bytes = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0)) > 0) {
        buffer[received_bytes] = '\0';
        response_stream << buffer;
    }
    response_stream << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Server Response: " << response_stream.str() << std::endl;

    // Close the socket
    closesocket(sock);

    // Cleanup Winsock
    WSACleanup();

    std::cout << "Time sent successfully." << std::endl;
```

I get the following result:

[image]

I have tried adding in "\n" to the end of the response from the server and a few others I have tried but as you can see in the image it cuts the first character off of each line there after the server response.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

I have tried a few combinations of ending a string line. Expecting that the characters all show up on command prompt.

**EDIT:**

So after a while of testing I found out that it was both the response from the server and my command that I had to send to it. Based on my testing if a string has a escape character sent to the console in it then it produces the problem I was asking about. Is there any way to prevent that from affecting the console?

I am declaring the escape like the following:

std::string uhr_null = "\x1b";

Comment: what is the contents of `response_stream`? Does it contain special characters such as carriage returns?

Comment: I would first try NOT emitting the characters from the response stream, and see if you still get that funnny behavior. If YES, then the problem has something todo with terminal settings/scrolling. If no, then look at the characters in your buffer. Instead of emitting them as a string, convert each one to a HEX number and dump it to screen, and see if any look  like funny/control characters.

Comment: Strange, and no explanation occurs to me. I suggest you cut the code down to it's bare minimum (so all the socket stuff and the response stream) that should give you two output statements, and presumably no problems. Then slowly reintroduce the eliminated code, at some point the strange behaviour will reoccur and at that point you'll hopefully have some idea what the problem is.

Comment: Incidentally `response_stream << buffer;` is not a valid way of adding arbitrary data to a stream, because the data will be truncated at the first null byte. You should prefer `response_stream.write(buffer, received_bytes);` This method also means you don't have to worry about adding a null terminator to `buffer`.

Comment: `buffer[received_bytes] = '\0'; response_stream << buffer;` -- You shouldn't be sticking characters into the stream that was returned -- what if the buffer has embedded nulls in it already?  As mentioned by @john, you display the buffer by `response_stream.write(buffer, received_bytes);`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I do believe there is some null characters being returned by the hosting application. I'll try the recommendations everyone has offered and return with more information and possibly a fix. Great advice everyone and it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not a null character, it's an escape.  Escapes are treated specially by many consoles and should be avoided.

Comment: Ahhh yes I will edit my response. Been a long day. I however have no way of avoiding this as this is required by the server. Is there any way to remove this limitation in the console? Like maybe Trim out the Escapes from the string before sending to the console?

Comment: You could trim them, or replace them with some other character.